Vue: Access v-slot variables from JS
Is it possible to read values of the v-slot of a component in the script?
Example template:
<cron-core v-model="value" :periods="periods" :format="format" v-slot="{fields, period, error}">
  {{period}}
  <div v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id">
    {{field.id}}....
  </div>
  <div>error: {{error}}</div>
</cron-core>

I'm trying to read the fields value without success. I cannot directly edit the sub-component, because is a predefined component.

What does read values mean?

Also how does it look? More context is welcome.

It might help if you look at some examples: transfer of variables and functions in slots (stackoverflow.com), Slots (vuejs.com). Declare <slot name="customSlotName" :fields :period :name> in YourComponent.vue, and can use <YourComponent><template #customSlotName="{ fields, period, error }"></YourComponent>. Default name will "default" to slot, if you don't set name attribute in <slot>, what can use <template #default>.

Consider explaining your whole case, this could be XY problem, but it's hard to judge because the question isn't specific enough. It needs to take into account what real "predefined component" is. "i'm triyng to read the 'fields' value without success," - it's unclear what's the problem and what's the meaning of "from JS". You're trying to read it in the template, not component script

Original comment

It might help if you look at some examples: transfer of variables and functions in slots (stackoverflow.com), Slots (vuejs.com). Declare <slot name="customSlotName" :fields :period :error> in YourComponent.vue, and can use <YourComponent><template #customSlotName="{ fields, period, error }"></YourComponent>. Default name will "default" to slot, if you don't set name attribute in <slot>, what can use <template #default>.

Example
In Vue.js, a slot is a way to render content from a child component into a parent component. Slots allow you to pass variables and functions from the child component to the parent component.

Slots, named slots, paramteres, etc. - Vue.js Docs

How to can declare a <slot> in a Component
To declare a slot in your Vue component, you can use the <slot> element with a name attribute:
<!-- YourComponent.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="customSlotName" :fields="fields" :period="period" :error="error">
       Can write default content here, but it's just a optional
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const fields = ['field1', 'field2']
const period = 'daily'
const error = null
</script>

How to can change content of <slot> when use YourComponent.vue
To use the slot in your parent component, you can wrap it with a <template> element and use the # symbol to specify the name of the slot:
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <YourComponent>
    <template #customSlotName="{ fields, period, error }">
      <!-- Use the variables here -->
      {{ fields }}
      {{ period }}
      {{ error ? 'Error!' : '' }}
    </template>
  </YourComponent>
</template>

<script setup>
import YourComponent from './components/YourComponent.vue'
</script>

